# $X(\omega)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n(\omega)2^{-n}$ is a Uniform Random Variable?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am working on a problem on the infinite coin-tossing space and I'm having trouble making any meaningful progress.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$, where $\Omega=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$, $F$ is the $\sigma$-field generated by the finite-dimensional sets, and $P$ is the coin(a fair coin) tossing probability. Finite dimensional sets are defined as sets $A=\{\omega\in\Omega\lvert(\omega_1,\omega_2,...,\omega_n)\in B\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$, $B\subset\{0,1\}^n$.

Define $X_n(\omega)=\omega_n \in\{0,1\}$ is the
result of the nth toss and define $X(\omega)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n(\omega)2^{-n}$.

- Show that the above series converges for every $\omega \in \Omega$ and defines a random variable taking values in $[0,1]$.
- Show that $X$ has uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

**My attempt**:

- I believe the series converges (absolutely) by using the comparison test with $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-n}$, as $X_n\leq 1$, and $\lvert X_n2^{-n} \rvert\leq\lvert2^{-n}\rvert$. Now I'm hoping to show that $$E=\{\omega :X(\omega)\in (a,b)\}\in\sigma(F)$$ as if that holds, I can conclude that any Borel set will be in $\sigma(F)$ as well, since $\{(a,b):a,b\in[0,1]\}$ generates all the Borel sets in $[0,1]$. Now I can certainly find $\omega$'s that will be in $E$, since $X$ is a binary expansion of some real number in $[0,1]$, but I'm a bit stuck at this point.
- I was given a hint to find $P(X\in[i2^{-m},(i+1)2^{-m}])$ for $i=0,...,2^{m}-1$. I'm not sure how to find the probabilities, and how it can help to show that $X$ has a uniform distribution.

Any help on both questions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Every real number has a binary expansion.

Comment: @user282639 Could you explain how that relates to the problem?

Comment: Since $P(X\in[i2^{-m},(i+1)2^{-m}])$ does not depend on $i$ it can help to show that $X$ has a uniform distribution.

Comment: @kludg I'm not sure how to compute the probabilities; what would the sketch of the proof (even if in general) look like to prove a r.v. is uniform? Also, I've made an edit to the post updating my progress.

Comment: @pilotmath are you sure that the coin is not necessarily fair?

Comment: @kludg the coin is fair by the construction of the problem, is it not?

Comment: Your never mention that the coin-tossing probability is $1/2$, is it?

Comment: @kludg it is a fair coin, I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is to use the connection with binary expansions.

Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and consider the sum $A: = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k} X_k(\omega) = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n 2^{n-k} X_k(\omega) $. Observe that the last sum is a binary representation of some integer $0\leq i \leq 2^n-1$, regardless of the outcomes $X_k(\omega)$. Due to the independence of $\{X_n\}$, for each fixed integer $0\leq i \leq 2^n - 1 $ we get $\mathbb{P}( A = \frac{i}{2^n}) = 2^{-n} $ since all bits $X_1(\omega),...,X_n(\omega)$ must coincide with the bits of the given integer $i$. On the other hand, for the rest of the sum in $X(\omega)$ we have
$$
0\leq \sum\limits_{k = n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} X_k(\omega) \leq \sum\limits_{k = n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}  = \frac{1}{2^n}.
$$
It follows that $\mathbb{P}(X(\omega) \in  [\frac{i}{2^n}, \frac{i+1}{2^n}] ) = 2^{-n}$. From here we get that $\mathbb{P}(X \leq \frac{i}{2^n} )  = \frac{i}{2^n}$.

Now if $F(x)$ is the cdf (distribution function) of $X$, we have $F(x) = 0 $ for $x\leq 0$, $F(x) = 1$ for $x\geq 1$ by trivial estimates, and $F(x) = x$ if $x \in [0,1] $ and is of the form $\frac{i}{2^n}$ (dyadic rational) for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $0\leq i \leq 2^n-1$.  Finally, using the right continuity of $F$ and density of dyadic rationals in $[0,1]$ we conclude that $F (x) = x$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and hence $X$ has uniform distribution in $[0,1]$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Do you have any comment on how I can go about showing that $X$ is a random variable before proving its uniform distribution?

Comment: $X$ is a limit of random variables (partial sums of the series representing it) hence is a random variable itself , as taking limits ( along with addition, multiplication and other elementary operations ) on random variables preserves the measurability.

Comment: I was under the impression that only $\liminf X_n$ and $\limsup X_n$ are random variables, at least the book I'm using has theorem for that only, is that applicable here?

Comment: If the limit exists, which is the case with $X$, then both $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ coincide with the limit, so you can refer to either of the results you mentioned for measurability of $X$.

Comment: thank you for that, does the limit exist simply because we defined $X$ to be the limit of the partial sums, and does having $2^{-n}$ multiplied to each random variable change anything? Also, is my approach as mentioned in the original post a dead-end, or could I possibly take that proof somewhere?

Comment: When we have an infinite series, it is effectievly a notation for the limit of the sequence of partial sums. In order not to say each time that we have a limit of some sequence, we denote that by an infinite sum symbol. The factors $1/2^n$ are crucial for convergence, they open a door to many nice convergence test for the series, such as the domination criteria you use above. As for your approach, the 1st part tries to prove measurability of $X$ directly from definition, which wouldn't be easy and is not necessary, since that is standard. The 2nd is what we used in the answer above.

Comment: that makes sense. Lastly, does having factors $2^{-n}$ on $X_n$ affect measurability of $X_n$ at all? Clearly each $X_n$ is measurable, but I'm not sure if each $X_n2^{-n}$ is measurable? (if it is, then I can extend that to $X$ being measurable as we've discussed above)

Comment: multiplying by a constant factor does not affect the measurability. Moreover, the product of two measurable functions (random variables) is always measurable.

Comment: For $X$ taking values in $[0,1]$, is it enough to mention that $X$ is in fact the formula for finding the binary expansion of any number in $[0,1]$, or would the simpler argument of $0\leq X_n2^{-n}\leq 2^{-n}$ and taking the limit of the partial sums which would bound $X$ s.t. $0\leq X\leq 1$ suffice?

Comment: the bound $0\leq X_n \leq 1$ is what you need to show $0\leq X \leq 1$.

Comment: thank you for your help!

Comment: btw, I noticed a typo, $2^{n-1}$ should be $2^n-1$ in the 3rd and the 4th line, right? Just wanted to make sure as some people may visit this page in the future

Comment: you're right, it must be $2^n - 1$, thanks for pointing out, I'll edit the post

Answer (score 2):

The intuition behind the proof is as follows. Let us start from $P(X\in[0,2^{-1}])$; the event of interest can occur in 2 ways:

- $X_1=0$;
- $X_1=1$, and all $X_i=0$, $i>1$.

The 2nd way has zero probability and we ignore it,
$$P(X\in[0,2^{-1}])=P(X_1=0)=2^{-1}$$

Arguing this way, we prove that
$$P(X\in[i2^{-m},(i+1)2^{-m}])=2^{-m}$$
because the event of interest is a unique combination of the values of random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_m$. For example,
$$P(X\in[2\cdot 2^{-2}, 3\cdot 2^{-2}])=P(X_1=1,X_2=0)=2^{-2}$$

Comment: thank you for the clear answer. Do you have any idea how I could move past the impasse(seemingly) on proving the measurability/that $X$ is a random variable?

Answer (score 1):

[image: 10,000 summations of n=12 coin flips each]

my contribution in providing histogram of a 10,000 runs of 12 flips