# Equidistributed Random Variables[No Fancy Stuff]

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let me first set up the background. It might be tedious but not fancy I promise.

Let the probability space be the interval $[0,1]$ of the real line. Let the sigma algebra be the sigma algebra generated by Lebesgue measurable sets on $[0,1]$. The probability measure is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.

Note that for every $\omega \in [0,1]$, we have the binary expansion as follows: $$\omega=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \beta_n 2^{-n},\,\text{where } \beta_n=\beta_n(\omega) \text{ which is either 0 or 1}.$$

Just by convention, we require one more condition that $\sum \beta_n = \infty$ except for $\omega=0$. This condition basically means that in the expansion there are infinitely many $1$'s.

Therefore, we can view $\beta_n$ as a function from $[0,1]$ to $\{0,1\}$, which is a random variable in our probability space.

For every fixed $j\in \mathbb N$, we may further define $$\omega_j=\omega_j(\omega)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb N} \beta_{m(n,j)}2^{-n},\text{ where }m \text{ is an arbitrary but fixed bijection between } \mathbb N^2 \mbox{ and } \mathbb N.$$

The author then wrote that, each of $\omega_j$ is equidistibuted on $[0,1]$, i.e., given a subinterval $I$ of $[0,1]$, the probability of the $\omega$-set where $\omega_j(\omega)\in I$ is the length of $I$.

**My question** is, why the probability of the $\omega$-set where $\omega_j(\omega)\in I$ is the length of $I$?

---

**My thoughts:** Given a fixed $\omega\in I$, we have its binary expansion, which determines all $\beta_n$'s. Fix $j\in \mathbb N$, $\{m(n,j)| n\in \mathbb N\}$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb N$, which means that, $\omega_j$ is defined by only using some of $\beta_n$'s. For those $n$ which are not used in defining $\omega_j$, even if we alter the values of the corresponding $\beta_n$ resulting in new $\tilde{\omega}$, we still have $\omega_j(\omega)=\omega_j(\tilde{\omega})$. Therefore, I guess we should have $|\omega_j^{-1}(I)|>|I|$, where $|\cdot|$ means Lebesgue measure rather than cardinality. (*I know my reasoning is all about cardinality and it is different from measure but they are also somehow related, especially speaking of Lebesgue measure. My argument may not be sufficient, but I still somehow believe my guess that $|\omega_j^{-1}(I)|>|I|$ shall be correct*).

---

Any comment or insight is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the setup completely, but here's a thought: Take $j\in\mathbb{N}$ with $1\notin\{m(n,j)\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Then $\omega_j(\omega)\leq1/2$ for any $\omega\in[0,1]$, right? So $\omega_j$ cannot be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @jakobdt Not really. We only know $m$ is a bijection between $\mathbb N^2$ and $\mathbb N$. So, given a fixed $j$, it is likely that $1\in \{m(n,j)|n\in \mathbb N \}$. I can explain the setup more briefly. First fix an $\omega \in [0,1]$ from which we get all $\beta_n$'s. Then we take some of $\beta_n$'s(infinitely many), shuffle, to form a new binary expansion.

Comment: If $m\colon\mathbb{N}^2\to\mathbb{N}$ is a bijection there is a unique pair $(j,n)\in\mathbb{N}^2$ such that $m(j,n)=1$.

Comment: @jakobdt We have fixed $j$. There exists some $(n,k)\in \mathbb N^2$ such that $m(n,k)=1$, but this $k$ may not be $j$. Basically, the union of sets $\{m(n,j)|n\in \mathbb N\}$ over all $j\in \mathbb N$, forms a partition of $\mathbb N$. This fact is almost trivial (and may not help I guess).

Comment: @jakobdt ... Well, I guess you didn't understand the setup at all. Fix $j$. $m(n,j)$ is a subscript(or index) for every $n\in \mathbb N$ and it determines $\beta_{m(n,j)}$. $\Longrightarrow \{ m(n,j)| n\in \mathbb N \}$ is a subset of $\mathbb N$. Therefore, $\{\beta_{m(n,j)} \}$ is a subsequence(with reordering) of $\{\beta_i\}_{i\in \mathbb N}$. It is then clear that $\omega_j([0,1])=[0,1]$. BTW, I'm a bit worried about your PhD QE in analysis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139916/discussion-between-sam-wong-and-jakobdt).

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it boils down to showing that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \kappa_n 2^{-n}$, where $\kappa_n$ are independent "symmetric" bits, has uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. This must have been asked and answered on this site a dozen times, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958675/x-omega-sum-n-1-infty-x-n-omega2-n-is-a-uniform-random-variable) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570573/distribution-of-infinite-sum-of-bernoulli)

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks for this point of view. I have a question though. If we know $\kappa_n$'s are independent, do we also have that $\kappa_{m(n,j)}$'s are also independent? Based on the definition of independence, it seems this is the case but I am just not so confident of this result.

Comment: Yes, this follows immediately from the definition of independence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claim: $\beta_n$s are i.i.d with $P(\beta_n = 0) = P(\beta_n = 1) = 1/2$. Actually it seems slightly easier to show the converse, i.e if $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is an i.i.d sequence uniformly distributed on $\{0, 1\}$, then $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}X_n2^{-n}$ is uniform on $[0, 1]$. Here it is easy to argue that the probabilities match for dyadic intervals of the form $[0, j2^{-n}]$, and then the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem implies that the probabilities match for all Borel subsets of $[0, 1]$.

Then the author's claim follows because $(\beta_{m(n, j)})_{n,j\in\mathbb{N}}$ are i.i.d.

Comment: I think it should be $X_n2^{-n}$. I also thought about using that. CDF is standard, for $(-\infty, j2^{-n}]$ we would first have to show that it generates the Borel algebra. Reward is that you don't have to take limits, like you said. I guess it's good to be aware of both, so you have a choice :-)

Comment: @Majita To show that the dyadic intervals generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, you can show that they generate any interval $[a, b]$ by taking limits. So I haven't really escaped taking limits.

Comment: @Mason Sorry for my late reply. Can you elaborate a bit on "*the probabilities match for dyadic intervals of the form $[0,j2^{-n}]$*", i.e. write out a bit more steps on this argument? Thank you so much.

Comment: @SamWong $P(.B_1B_2 \dots \leq 0.b_1b_2 \dots) = 2^{-1}b_1 + 2^{-1}P(0.B_2 B_3 \dots \leq 0.b_2b_3 \dots)$. So $F(0.b_1b_2 \dots) = 2^{-1}b_1 + 2^{-1}F(0.b_2b_3 \dots)$.

Answer (score 1):

First, we notice that $\beta_n$ is measurable.
For this purpose let $q(b)=\sum_{k=1}^nb_k2^{-k}$ be the number for $b\in\{0,1\}^n$,
and notice that $\{\omega\in[0,1]:\beta_n(\omega)=0\}=\bigcup_{b\in\{0,1\}^{n-1}}[q(b,0),q(b,1))$ is measurable. Further, notice that since $q(b,1)=q(b,0)+2^{-n}$, each interval has length $2^{-n}$ and hence $\mathbb P(\beta_n=0)=2^{n-1}\cdot 2^{-n}=0.5$. Next, we show that the distribution of $(\beta_n)_n$ is the product measure. Using the [Ionescu-Tulcea Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionescu-Tulcea_theorem), it is sufficient to show that $\beta_n$ is independent of $(\beta_k)_{k<n}$ for all $n$. But we have just seen that $\mathbb P(\beta_n=0|\beta_{[n-1]}=b)=0.5$ for all $b\in\{0,1\}^{n-1}$, where $\beta_{[n-1]}=(\beta_k)_{k\in[n-1]}$. Hence, $\beta_n$ does not depend on its predecessors and the joint distribution of $(\beta_k)_k$ is the product measure.

To see that $(\beta_{m(n,j)})_{n,j}$ has the same distribution, we may proceed accordingly. We could show this by using the order given by $n,j$.
However, it is more instructive to observe that the order does not matter.
For this purpose notice that $\mathbb P(\beta_2=b_2,\beta_1=b_1)=\mathbb P(\beta_1=b_1,\beta_2=b_2)=0.5\cdot 0.5$ and this clearly extends to any rearrangement of $\beta_{[n]}$. The fact that $(\beta_i)_{i\in\mathcal N}$ for a subset $\mathcal N\subseteq[n]$ is still i.i.d. Bernoulli with success probability $0.5$ can be seen by expanding the complete joint distribution and aggregating, say \begin{aligned}
\mathbb P(\beta_1=b_1,\beta_3=b_3)
&=\mathbb P(\beta_1=b_1,\beta_2=0,\beta_3=b_3)+\mathbb P(\beta_1=b_1,\beta_2=1,\beta_3=b_3)\\
&=0.125+0.125=0.25,
\end{aligned} so, beyond all doubt, no matter what selection $\beta_{\mathcal N}$, they are i.i.d. Bernoulli with success probability $0.5$.

So, in particular any selection $(\beta_{m(n,j)})_{(n,j)\in\mathcal S}$, for any finite $\mathcal S\subseteq\mathbb N^2$, is also i.i.d. Bernoulli.
And this means that the distribution of $(\beta_{m(n,j)})_{n}$ for fixed $j$ ist still the product measure given by the theorem above.

Next, we show that $\omega_j$ is measurable, which is all but obvious. But notice that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}q((\beta_{m(k,j)})_{k\in[n]})=\omega_j$ from below, and the $q$'s are clearly measurable, being just linear combinations, and non-negative, so $\omega_j$ is measurable because it is both the [pointwise limit and the supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function), and we obtain the distribution of $\omega_j$ using the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) (since probabilities are also just integrals), yielding
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(\omega_j\in\mathcal E)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb P(q((\beta_{m(k,j)})_{k\in[n]})\in\mathcal E).
\end{align*}
Now, we can use Theorem 1.23 with Remark 1.24 and Lemma 1.42 in Klenke's Probability Theory, i.e. it is sufficient to show that $\mathbb P(\omega_j\in(-\infty,a])=\int_{(0,1)\cap(-\infty,a]}\mathrm dx$. For $a<0$ and $a>1$ this holds by the above, so let $a\in[0,1]$. The sequence $P_n=\mathbb P(q((\beta_{m(k,j)})_{k\in[n]})\in(-\infty,a])$ gives weight $2^{-n}$ to each $b\in\{0,1\}^{n}$ with $q(b)\le a$. How many are there? Let $a=\sum_{k=1}^\infty b^*_k$, then we count from including $0$ to $(b^*_k)_{k\in[n]}$ in binary numbers, meaning that we count $\sum_{k=1}^n2^{n-k}b^*_k+1$ numbers, yielding $P_n=\sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k}b^*_k+n^{-1}$, which converges to $a$ by the above. This shows that $\omega_j$ is uniform.

Finally, we also want to see that $\omega_i,\omega_j$ are independent for $i\neq j$.
For this purpose we consider the joint distribution $\mathbb P(\omega_i\in\mathcal E,\omega_j\in\mathcal F)$ and approximate it by $\mathbb P(q((\beta_{m(i,k)})_{k\in[n]}\in\mathcal E,q((\beta_{m(j,k)})_{k\in[n]}\in\mathcal F)$. Since the $\beta$'s are independent, this factorizes, and using the generator $(-\infty,a]\times(-\infty,b]$ we obtain the result analogously. This can be further extended to any finite selection $\omega_{\mathcal J}$, thus this result shows how we can create countably many i.i.d. copies of $\omega$.

**EDIT** In its essence, this construction is nothing but a countably infinite version of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4558343/mapping-u-v-in0-1-uniformly-to-a-star-shaped-form/4559226#4559226) construction (the first item).

Comment: Hi Matija, thanks for your reply. I will take some time to read your post later (because now I am a bit too busy to read the theory on the machinery you used).

Comment: You're welcome, I'm also happy to answer follow-up questions.